# LINUX: tar: You may not specify more than one '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or '--test-label' option

Tags: linux, tar, chrome-os

`sudo tar xuzf splunk-7.2.4-8a94541dcfac-Linux-x86_64.tgz -C /opt`

I get the following message:

`tar: You may not specify more than one '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or  '--test-label' option`
`Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.`

Note: I am on a google pixelbook running chromeos and using the Linux terminal.

Edit: I am following a tutorial for this and it worked perfectly for the person I am watching.

Comment: Are you still sure that in the tutorial `u`  worked instead of `v`?

Comment: PRY is right, you are mistaking a v for a u. Youtube tutorial....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You either extract (`x`) the archive or update (`u`) the archive: you can't do both at the same time.

Most likely you misread a `v` (for verbose) into a `u`.

So what you need would be:

```
sudo tar xvzf splunk-7.2.4-8a94541dcfac-Linux-x86_64.tgz -C /opt
```

Answer (score 0):

`x`/`-x`/`--extract` is for extracting files out of the archive, `u`/`-u`/`--update` is to add modified files to the archive. It doesn't make sense to do both at the same time. The other ones mentioned (`Acdtrux`) are similarly incompatible.

Could it be that you were trying to extract files from the archive but misread `v` (verbose) as `u`? `tar xvzf` would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says you can use only one option.

From `man tar`:

```
    -u, --update
          Append files which are newer than the corresponding copy in  the
          archive.   Arguments  have  the  same  meaning as with -c and -r
          options.

   -x, --extract, --get
          Extract files from an archive.  Arguments  are  optional.   When
          given,   they  specify  names  of  the  archive  members  to  be
          extracted.
```

So `u` option will append files (update) files while `x` will extract. As the other answers suggested, maybe you misspelled `u` instead of `v` (verbose).

So the final command will be like:

```
sudo tar xvzf splunk-7.2.4-8a94541dcfac-Linux-x86_64.tgz -C /opt
```